# Rails ajax calls not finding variable when sending it via partial locals

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I am trying to implement a Like/Unlike system in my web app.

This is the error I am getting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `task' for #<#<Class:0x007f909b6cc680>:0x007f909b65dfa0>
Did you mean?  @task):
    1: <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.likes?(task) %>
    2:  <%= link_to "Downvote/Unlike", task_like_path(task), method: :delete, remote: true %>
    3: <% else %>
    4:  <%= link_to "Upvote/Like", task_like_path(task), method: :post, remote: true %>

app/views/tasks/_likes.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks__likes_html_erb__4604839685375789387_70129528145700'
app/views/tasks/likes/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks_likes_destroy_js_erb__2774523607266188291_70129537297860'
```

The problem I have been facing is that I have no show action in my Tasks controller. Instead, I am using a modal called from the tasks#index path. That means I am iterating over my `@tasks` from my index controller method, and sending each individual task as a local to my modal partial.

I am attempting to do the same with Liking/Unliking. I will paste in my code below

This is what my likes controller looks like:

```
def create
    @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @task.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render partial: "shared/task_modal", task: @task }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This is how I am calling my Tasks#Show modal from index.html.erb:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
   <h2><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> <%= link_to task.title, 'javascript:void(0)', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#task_modal' %></h2>
   <%= render "shared/task_modal", task: task %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the main chunk of my task_modal partial:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <p><%= task.description %></p>
        <i><%= task.reward %> OMG</i><br>
        <i><%= task.difficulty.titleize %></i><br>
        <i>Max submissions: <%= task.max_submissions %></i>
        <hr>
        <!-- Add logic here for admin (if admin, show following button) -->
        <%= link_to "Edit Task", edit_task_path(task), class: "btn btn-secondary btn-mini" %>
      </div>

      <div id="likes">
        <%= render 'likes', task: task %>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
```

My `views/tasks/likes/create.js.erb` and my `destroy.js.erb` looks like this:

`$('#likes').html("<%= j render partial: 'tasks/likes', task: task %>");`

Yet for some reason when j rendering a partial I cannot send the task local. What is the solution for this, besides creating an instance variable for task?

EDIT:
I just tried removing `partial` from my j render. That gives me the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `task' for #<#<Class:0x007f909b6cc680>:0x007f90a2afb8a8>
Did you mean?  @task):
    1: $('#likes').html("<%= j render 'tasks/likes', task: task %>");

app/views/tasks/likes/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks_likes_create_js_erb___3082837621974805143_70129597727640'
```

Is there a way I can send the task variable to my js files?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. So I have @task declared in my Tasks controller under create and destroy actions. That means it is served to the show and destroy js.erb files. All I had to do was change my js to use the instance variable as a local like so: `$('#likes').html("<%= j render 'tasks/likes', task: @task %>");`